# Compatible Versions: Ember, Ember Data, Handlebars

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to learn Ember.js by following TodoMVC example. I am quite confused on with versions of Ember, Ember Data and Handlebars are compatible. The tutorial  states following

> Blockquote
>   The latest release candidate (RC3) of Ember.js can be downloaded directly from the Ember.js website. Ember.js has two dependencies: jQuery and Handlebars. jQuery can be downloaded from at http://jquery.com/ and Handlebars can be downloaded at http://handlebarsjs.com/. This guide uses ember-data for managing model data. The latest development builds of Ember data can be downloaded at http://builds.emberjs.com/. The build compatible with RC3 has the SHA e324f0e.

The Ember RC3 is no longer in download link. It has RC5. Can any one please help me which versions should I use?

Thanks

Comment: The starter kit has Ember.js rc 5. Which version of EmberData is compatible with Ember.jas RC 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the latest versions are

- [handlebars 1.0](https://raw.github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/1.0.0/dist/handlebars.js)
- [ember rc.5](http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-1.0.0-rc.5.js)
- [ember-data 0.13](http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-data-0.13.js)

All of those versions were bumped within the last week, so there won't be a lot of information the web just yet. You can download them from their respective websites (for ember-data [read the blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/05/28/ember-data-0-13.html) on the emberjs website. The link is in the comments)

I'd suggest you use the latest versions if you're starting out. Not much has changed in ember since RC-3, so you won't miss anything. I suggest you read some of the blog posts on the ember site for the changes in each revision. The team is very good in putting up explanations on the blog regarding updates.

Comment: Ember RC5 uses handlerbars 1.0.0.RC4

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot. Handlebars 1.0 is in fact incompatible with rc.5, as I found out from [this issue](https://github.com/bartsqueezy/ember-handlebars-brunch/issues/4)